# CSRF verification failed: is token not persisting between GET and POST? Django

Tags: python, django, post

I checked a lot of the older CSRF questions, but they seem to be from 5+ years ago and a lot of the solutions aren't applicable due to now being handled with render() or other built-in methods. So, here's my question:

I'm rendering a form template from a class-based view. It loads fine when I hit the initial GET request, but when I try to submit, it throws a `403: CSRF verification failed` error.

I'm not sure why this is happening - I feel like I'm doing everything right. Could it have something to do with saved cookies that override the CSRF token getting changed every time `render` is called? Here's my code:

```py
class Intake(View):
    form_class = IntakeFormSimple
    template_name = "intake.html"

    def get(self, req: HttpRequest):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(req, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, req: HttpRequest):
        form = self.form_class(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # PLACEHOLDER: I DO SOME STUFF WITH THE SUBMITTED DATA HERE
            return HttpResponse("submitted form!")
        return render(req, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

and the form template (boilerplate removed for clarity):

```html
<body>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
          {% csrf_token %} {{ form.non_field_errors }} {% for field in form %}
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}"
              >{{field.label}}</label
            >
            <div class="control">{{field}}</div>
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{field.help_text}}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <ul class="errorlist">
              {% for error in field.errors %}
              <li class="is-danger help">{{error}}</li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

**#in views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def myView(request):
  #your code
```

Comment: Hmm. I know I could do that, I'm using it for testing. But, isn't it bad practice to disable csrf tokens?

Comment: it totally depends on the type of form (i.e is form data sensitive or not). CSRF is not for data validation but for checking whether the request is coming from a trusted (maybe the same) origin or not.

Comment: I would say yes, this form data could be sensitive.